# Forcing AWS to allow query to NOT EXECUTE on Replication

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-rds

We are using AWS with replication on our system.

This automatically switches to replication databases for queries that do not modify data.

However we have one query that calls a MySQL function which DOES modify the database.  The function merely creates a placeholder record with a unique ID and returns that via a select statement.  Something akin to:

"SELECT GenerateUniqueID()"

Function Def:

```
SELECT MAX(lngInvoiceID)
INTO @lngMaxInvoiceID
FROM invoice_table
WHERE GlobalConfigID=in_GlobalConfigID
FOR UPDATE;
SET @lngNewInvoiceID=COALESCE(@lngMaxInvoiceID+1,1);
INSERT INTO invoice_table(datCreated,GlobalConfigID,lngInvoiceID)
VALUES(CURDATE(),in_GlobalConfigID,@lngNewInvoiceID);
RETURN @lngNewInvoiceID;
```

However, this will fail with MySQL error "The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement".

GenerateUniqueID function in MySQL has its "Data Access" attribute set to "Modifies SQL Data" and this seems to make no difference.

The DB connection is definetly to the load balancer.

Is there some way to FORCE the query to operate off the node that is NOT replication??

Comment: are you using RDS, or are you rolling your own replication?

Comment: Yes - we are using RDS.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your load balancer.  What load balancer are you using?

Comment: Load Balancer with E2 as part of AWS.  That side seems to be fine - we suspect it's the mysqlnd_ms.  It seems to take the SELECT, switch from the write node back to the replication and execute it.  Bang - at that point when I dump the connection, it is definitely pointed to replication.  The MySQL function executes with writes and fails as the rep is of course read-only.

Comment: I have been able to get around this through bypassing the load balancer and connecting directly to the master.  This is not good practice, but it does mean the connection doesn't shunt across to replication and fail.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the load balancer and connected directly to the master.  That seems to stop the connection being shifted to replication.  Not an ideal fix, but it did fix the issue for me.